# how to correctly display an xml data in a php page for php5

Tags: php, xml

Hello there I have an xml data in my sql the problem is once I display those data onto my page I get them as string. However i was able to devise a solution to this by converting it into htmlentities. But I think this taking a lot of time to load or would cause the display not too load at all. I've researched about this problem but I was wondering since it's already php5 isn't there a much simpler way of converting your data into xml to display in a page?

here's a sample of my code:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db("globetosmac_db");

$requestdate = date("Y-m-d");
$requesttime = date("H:i:s");
$requestsql  = "SELECT xml FROM g2s_api_logs "         .
               "WHERE functioncode   = 'MQX' "         .
               "  AND cardnumber     = '$cardnumber' " .
               "  AND direction      = 'out' "         .
               "  AND DATE(datetime) = '$requestdate' AND " .
               "  AND TIME(datetime) = '$requesttime'";

$requestquery  = mysql_query($requestsql) or die(mysql_error() . $requestsql);
$requestarray  = mysql_fetch_array($requestquery, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$requestresult = htmlentities($requestarray['xml']);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Whether `htmlentities` is slow? Do you just *think* that it's slow or *is* it slow? Do you want to use the XML data as XML or as human-readable example? What the end goal here?

Comment: yah if using html entities will cause a slow load on my display, because the table data is already in xml format, the problem is once i take them out they become a string.what do you mean by human-readable example? omitting the xml format? if so i want the data to be displayed as XML data if that makes sense :)

Comment: XML is just text, I don't know what you mean by "when I take them out they become a string". XML === string === text. What I mean is, why are you HTML escaping your XML data?

Comment: because i need them in xml format i don't need them to display as string what i meant by string is this <sample>Hello World</sample> just becomes Hello World in short it only displays what's inside the tag but i need them in a format where i can also see the tags as well

Comment: thinking about it now I did make it a little confusing so I'm replacing the word string to plain text :) sorry about that

Comment: @deceze im reading your article about Great Escapism right now btw :)

Comment: So, do *you* want to read the XML in a browser or do you just want to *output* the XML to be consumed by some other service? Because it's just the browser interpreting the XML tags, they're actually still there if you look into View Source. Maybe The Great Escapism will clear up your confusion... :)

Comment: I want to output the xml into my php page with the xml tags included in the output. As i said htmlentities work fine to achieve this format but you actually have to refresh the page to see them :) so if its working fine once i view my source the problem would have to be the query for retrieving the data :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you are using XML inside an SQL DB but if I were you, I would add just the plain text into the database, and make rows for each section of the XML.

From

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to>John</to>
    <from>Bill</from>
    <heading>What's Up?</heading>
    <body>How are you doing?</body>
</note>
```

To

```
Table:    NOTE
Rows:     To    From    Heading    Body
          John  Bill    What's Up? How are you doing?
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but the application is storing data as xml through XML-RPC implementation so I don't think that converting my sql table field would solve my problem :) were kind of using xml to call a WEB API so i think I need it in xml format